# What is the asymptotic lower bound for the time complexity of the algorithm given below?

Tags: big-o, lower-bound

What is the asymptotic lower bound for the time complexity of the algorithm given below?

MysteryAlgorithm

Input: a1, a2,...,an
          n, the length of the sequence.
          p, a number.
Output: ??

```
i := 1

j := n

While (i < j)

      While (i < j and ai < p)
            i := i + 1
      End-while
      While (i < j and aj ≥ p)
            j := j - 1
      End-while
      If (i < j)
            swap ai and aj
End-while

Return( a1, a2,...,an )
```

Choices:

A. Ω(n)

B. Ω(n^2)

C. O(n^2)

D. Θ(n)

E. Θ(n^3)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include your thoughts what the correct answer would be and why do you think that would be the correct answer.

Comment: I know for sure that it isn't B. Ω(n^2).  I think it might be A. Ω(n).

Comment: Please edit your question to include the reason why you think it is solution A) and what your struggle is to verify that is is in fact solution A) (or to verify it's not).

Comment: I think it might be A. Ω(n) because the first while loop will exit after the first round if i < j.